# Oracle BPM 12c - Using external UI for Human Task Initiator sends 404-popup

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c, business-process-management

I have an Initiator task, assosiated to a Human Task which points to an external UI (deployed on a tomcat).

Mostly, it works as expected (the link appears on the workspace, under "Applications", I can click it and it instantiates correctly, and this task on the workspace redirects to the webpage I deployed on the tomcat.

The unexpected behaviour occurs in between, when I Click on the Application Link, and it shows a popup redirecting to a "404 - Not found"

[image]

The URL of the 404 page is the following:

> http://localhost:7001/bpm/workspace/faces/adf.task-flow?adf.tfId=taskDetail-task-flow-definition&adf.tfDoc=/WEB-INF/taskDetail-task-flow-definition.xml&taskId=621bb052-b956-4a63-af6a-efefc91ad5c6&instanceId=30009&mode=initiatorDialog&consumingApp=workspace&refreshURL=http://localhost:7001/bpm/workspace/faces/jsf/worklist/worklist.jspx&fetchNextTaskButtonId=&fetchPreviousTaskButtonId=&refreshTaskListButtonId=&fetchNewTaskButtonId=&fetchSameTaskButtonId=&language=es&country=AR&variant=&_afrLoop=61651218347370&_afrWindowMode=0&Adf-Window-Id=_appTaskForm45&_afrFS=16&_afrMT=screen&_afrMFW=800&_afrMFH=591&_afrMFDW=1536&_afrMFDH=864&_afrMFC=8&_afrMFCI=0&_afrMFM=0&_afrMFR=120&_afrMFG=0&_afrMFS=0&_afrMFO=0

And the error trace:

> <_logUnhandledException>
>
> oracle.adf.controller.ControllerException: ADFC-06018: Task flow ID EL expression '#{pageFlowScope.taskDetailsView.remoteTaskDefId}' on activity '/WEB-INF/taskDetail-task-flow-definition.xml#taskDetail-task-flow-definition@remoteTaskFlowCall' evaluated to null.
>
> at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.getTaskFlowDefinitionId(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:1155)
>
> at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.execute(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:115)
>
> at oracle.adfinternal.controller.engine.ControlFlowEngine.executeActivity(ControlFlowEngine.java:1241)
>
> at oracle.adfinternal.controller.engine.ControlFlowEngine.doRouting(ControlFlowEngine.java:1087)
>
> at oracle.adfinternal.controller.engine.ControlFlowEngine.doRouting(ControlFlowEngine.java:979)
>
> at oracle.adfinternal.controller.engine.ControlFlowEngine.invokeTaskFlow(ControlFlowEngine.java:253)
>
> at oracle.adfinternal.controller.application.RemoteTaskFlowCallRequestHandler.invokeTaskFlowByUrl(RemoteTaskFlowCallRequestHandler.java:103)
>
> at oracle.adfinternal.controller.application.RemoteTaskFlowCallRequestHandler.doCreateView(RemoteTaskFlowCallRequestHandler.java:64)
>
> at oracle.adfinternal.controller.application.BaseRequestHandlerImpl.createView(BaseRequestHandlerImpl.java:59)
>
> at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.InternalViewHandlingStrategy.createView(InternalViewHandlingStrategy.java:48)
>
> at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.createView(MultiViewHandler.java:160)
>
> at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.createView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:170)
>
> at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.createView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:108)
>
> at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._restoreView(LifecycleImpl.java:847)
>
> at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:397)
>
> at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:225)
>
> at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>
> at oracle.help.web.rich.OHWFilter.doFilter(OHWFilter.java:197)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>
> at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:192)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>
> at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
>
> at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
>
> at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
>
> at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
>
> at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:327)
>
> at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:229)
>
> at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>
> at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:202)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>
> at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:137)
>
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>
> at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
>
> at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
>
> at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:120)
>
> at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:217)
>
> at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:81)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>
> at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:137)
>
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>
> at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
>
> at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
>
> at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:120)
>
> at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:217)
>
> at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:81)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>
> at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:220)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
>
> at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>
> at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
>
> at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
>
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
>
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

I'd like to know both the motive and possible solutions to this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace 'localhost' in url with '127.0.0.1', then it'll work.